# $ is not defined in my javascript console

Tags: javascript, html

i am learning programming and trying my hand at the first website. Every time i run my code i get the error `$ is not defined` on the line `$(document).ready(function(){` 
I have added some of my code below, thanx in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var mechanical = {
        program: "Engineering",
        course: "Mechanical Engineering",
        tuition: 1000000
    }

    var electrical = {
        program: "Engineering",
        course: "Electrical Engineering",
        tuition: 1000000
    }
    var telecom = {
        program: "Engineering",
        course: "Telecom Engineering",
        tuition: 1000000
    }
    var civil = {
        program: "Engineering",
        course: "Civil Engineering",
        tuition: 1000000
    }

    var courses = [mechanical, electrical, telecom, civil];

    if ($('#program_selector').text() == "Engineering"){
        //then load engineering courses
        var selectedCourses = [];
        for (var i = 0; courses[i]; i++){
            if (courses[i].program == "Engineering") {
                //find courses where program is engineering and add name to selected courses array
                //selectedCourses.push(courses[i].program);
                //add to options to select
                var x = document.getElementById("#course_selector");
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.text = courses[i].program;
                x.add(option);

            }
        }
    }
    else if ($('#program_selector').text() == "Agriculture") {
        //then load the agriculture courses
        var selectedCourses = [];
        for (var i = 0; courses[i]; i++){
            if (courses[i].program == "Agriculture") {
                //find courses where program is engineering and add name to selected courses array
                //selectedCourses.push(courses[i].program);
                //add to options to select
                var x = document.getElementById("#course_selector");
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.text = courses[i].program;
                x.add(option);

            }
        }
    }
    else if ($('#program_selector').text() == "Ict") {
        //then load ICT courses
        var selectedCourses = [];
        for (var i = 0; courses[i]; i++){
            if (courses[i].program == "Ict") {
                //find courses where program is engineering and add name to selected courses array
                //selectedCourses.push(courses[i].program);
                //add to options to select
                var x = document.getElementById("#course_selector");
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.text = courses[i].program;
                x.add(option);

            }
        }
    }
});



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Victoria Webpage</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/style.css">
        <script src="assets/script.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div width="100%"; class="main">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="title">
                    <h1 align="center"; style = "background-color: red;color:white;">Victoria College</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="navigation">

                    <div class="navigation-right">
                        <ul class="nav_list">
                            <li class="nav_tabs"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="nav_tabs"><a href="about_us.html">About Us</a></li>
                            <li class="nav_tabs"><a href="programs.html">Programs</a></li>
                            <li class="nav_tabs"><a href="tuition.html">Tuition</a></li>
                            <li class="nav_tabs"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <h1 style="color:blue">TUITION AND COURSE FILLING FORM</h1>
            <form id="costForm" >
    <div>
        <label id="program_selector">Sector:</label>
        <!--<input type="text" name="sector" id="sector" tabindex="1">-->
        <select>
            <option></option>
            <option>Engineering</option>
            <option>Ict</option>
            <option>Agriculture</option>
        </select>       
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <label id="course_selector">Course:</label>
        <!--<input type="text" name="course" tabindex="1">-->
        <select>
            <option></option>
        </select>
    </div>  
    <br>        
    <div>
        <label for="annual_tuition">Annual Tuition:</label>
        <input type="value" name="annual_tuition" id="annual_tuition" value="" tabindex="1">
     </div>
     <br>
        <div>
        <label for="semester_tuition">Semester tuition:</label>
        <input type="value" name="semester_tuition" id="semester_tuition" value="" tabindex="1">
     </div>
     <br>
    <div>
         <button id="cost" type="button">Calculate</button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="costTotal"></div>

</form>

            <div align="center" class="footer">victoriacollege.sc</div> 
        </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Load in jQuery library

Comment: have you added jquery library?

Comment: Where are you defining `$`? You aren't doing in that code. Are you loading it from another JS file?

Comment: `$` is always defined in your javascript console in modern browsers ?

Comment: Load the jQuery library *before* you load your jQuery code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import jQuery script, add this in your html **before** your `<script>` tag:

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Update:

After question edit, I saw the problem:

```
<script src="assets/script.js"></script>
<script src="assets/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```

You're loading your script, which is using jQuery, before actual jQuery script. **Order matters!**

Fix: (load library script(s) frist, then load your code)

```
<script src="assets/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to download jQuery first [jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js)

after you have downloaded jquery.js put it in the directory where you html file is located and in the `<head>` element of you html write `<script src = 'jquery.js' ></script>`

Comment: Can you expand your answer to include how to actually load jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

1) You have written your JQuery code outside html code.

You have included JQuery library but you should write JQuery code after that and within script tag either inside head or body tag.

Either 
    $(document).ready(function(){....});
Or
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){....});

2) You have mixed up core JavaScript and JQuery code but you should follow one of them to have a standard in your code.

e.g.
    document.getElementById("#course_selector"); is not a proper way.

Answer (score -1):

I assume, that your Javascript-Code is stored in the file «script.js». The jQuery-Library is loaded after that script. That means, that the variable «$» becomes defined after you actually try to use it. Just change the order of the Script tags like this:

```
<script src="assets/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to include jQuery before calling it, so move your entire $(document).ready function to AFTER the

```
<script src="assets/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```

line.  Anywhere after is fine.